# Formal approach for text processing

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, compiler-theory, automata

During a coding interview I was asked the next question:

> Write a program which counts the number of words and lines in the input stream.
>       Assume you have a reader with method nextChar().

At the first glance it looks simple. But then you realize, that you need to handle a lot of states, like:

- a consecutive word/line delimeters
- different end-of-word conditions - words separator or line separator or EOF
- new string which starts with words separators
- etc

On the interview I came up with a sortof spagetti code with many if-else and flags.

But I think there should be a formal approach for this kind of problems, which allows you to guarantee that you handled all possible cases, and which can give a structured solution.

I think it maybe something either from automata theory, or from compilers theory (I've never made a deep dive to any of these two areas before).

So, if you recognize a certain type of problem in the problem above, or you know which theory covers problems like this, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Finite state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

This is essentially a small [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) task. The solution will never be pretty but if you write your code in the following way you can be quite confident of correctness:

```
curState <- NONE
while(c <- getChar)
    switch(curState) {
       case NONE:
           switch(c) {
               // ....
           }
           break;
       // .....
    }
}
```

You can also use a data structure to store the transition function (given a state and a character, what is the next state?) but for your case just writing the code is probably the best bet.

... don't forget about your text encoding! UTF-16, right? :)

You might want to look into implementations of the Unix `wc` utility:

- [Busybox](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/wc.c)
- [GNU](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/wc.c;hb=HEAD)
- [DragonFly BSD](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/DragonFly-BSD/usr.bin/wc/wc.c)
- [Mac OS X (from FreeBSD)](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-84/wc/wc.c)

These will be more polished and featured than what you will do in an interview, but its nice to see regardless.

Comment: We assumed that nextChar() method returned UTF-8 character or null if EOF.